# Spring PDF viewer :Fail to load pdf Document?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to display pdf in the browser .But it is not working giving error "Fail to load pdf Document". We used Spring to Display PDF. Here is my code to display pdf. Anyone can help me please to resolve this issue.

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<byte[]> generateReportByJavaList(List<T> listValues) {

        this.jasperPrint = null;
        try {
            File temp;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pdfFileName)) {
                temp = new File(pdfFileName);
            } else {
                temp = File.createTempFile(this.tempPrefix, ".pdf");
            }

            this.jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.reportFile, this.params,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listValues, false));

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, temp.getAbsolutePath());

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
            Path p = Paths.get(temp.getAbsolutePath());
            String filename = p.getFileName().toString();
            headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
            headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response1 = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>( headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            return response1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "generateReportByJavaList :" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (JRException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "generateReportByJavaList :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```